# Webpack cannot resolve module for custom definition file

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, types

I wanted to create d.ts file for my js library. However when I want to import this module into my ts file webpack throws error:

```
ERROR in ./index.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'TestModule'
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
- root
  --definitions
    -- TestModule
      --index.d.ts

  --src
    --index.ts
    --index.html

  --tsconfig.json
  --webpack.config.js
```

tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./definitions"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

webpack.config

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const isProd = nodeEnv === 'production';

const plugins = [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(nodeEnv)
    }
  }),
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Typescript Webpack Starter',
    template: '!!ejs-loader!src/index.html'
  }),
  new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
    options: {
      tslint: {
        emitErrors: true,
        failOnHint: true
      }
    }
  })
];

var config = {
  devtool: isProd ? 'hidden-source-map' : 'source-map',
  context: path.resolve('./src'),
  entry: {
    app: './index.ts'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('./dist'),
    filename: '[name].bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: [/\/node_modules\//],
        use: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'source-map-loader']
      },
      !isProd
        ? {
            test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
            loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
            exclude: [/\/node_modules\//],
            query: {
              esModules: true
            }
          }
        : null,
      { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] }
    ].filter(Boolean)
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  plugins: plugins,
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist/'),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    hot: true
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

index.ts

```
import TestModule from 'TestModule';

console.log(TestModule.sum(1, 2));
```

and definition file - index.d.ts

```
interface ITestModule {
    sum(number1: number, number2: number):number;
}

declare const TestModule: ITestModule;

declare module "TestModule" {
    export default TestModule;
}
```

I can see types when I import TestModule, but I have no idea why webpack throws me error.

@Edit

When I deleted the import statemnet it seems to work, I don't receiving any errors. However when I open application in the browser I can see

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for '...d.ts file'
```

Comment: have you installed "TestModule"? does it exists in node_modules?

Comment: No, it is my custom d.ts file, which I created under the definitions folder.

Comment: your cusomt d.ts file is somthing for existing javascript code, d.ts has no implementation only says typescrpt something about types. console.log(TestModule.sum(1, 2)); there has to be implementation of this function

Comment: I know that. I have my own library written in pure JS. I only wanted to add types to this library.

Comment: import TestModule from 'TestModule'; default root is node_modules so tscompliler or   some any loader will look there. if it is your file somewhere in your source you have to import that file. like import TestModule from 'src/components/TestModule'. and your d.ts definition should be there as well

Comment: @JurajKocan I defined defaults roots in tsconfing under the 'typeRoots' key...

Comment: and what is location of your module with implementation? what are you expectiong to compler to import? like i said. import TestModule from 'Testmodule' compiler is looking in node_modules for module. you can define typesRoot. whits is ok. it works for you. but it wont compile real file if it is not in node_modules